# Escape characters in ETW format strings?

Tags: c#, event-log, etw, etw-eventsource

I'm using the new EventSource class to write to the Windows Event log from my applications, and so far it's great. However, there are two things that I observe that are causing problems that are probably related: the format strings passed to the Event attribute don't appear to undergo normal string.Format processing before being written to the event log.

Consider this block:

```
[Event((int)LogEvent.UserCreated, Keywords=Keywords.Directory, Channel=EventChannel.Operational,
Message="Created username {0} with forum post signature {1} and homepage {2}.")]
public void UserCreated(string username, string signature, string homepageAddress)
{
    WriteEvent((int)LogEvent.UserCreated, username, signature, homepageAddress);
}
```

A few things occur:

- If I try to insert a \n into the format string for the message, no newline is printed in the event log.
- If the signature string contains a newline, the newline is printed naturally in the event log.
- If the signature or homepageAddress strings contain ETW-like tokens (%1, %2, or %3), then ETW begins replacing those pseudo-tokens with the variables themselves, and I end up with variables nested within themselves.

I assume that if there was an escape character for ETW, it could be used to put newlines in format strings, and would also allow me to pre-process my string values to protect against these sql-injection style bugs.

Does such an escape character exist? How is this usually done?

Comment: Keep in mind that logging should be fast and light weight. You don't want your pretty formatting to become a bottleneck.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, but that's the joy of ETW.  Formatting is performed by the consumer, not on write of an event.  If no-one looks, there is no formatting cost.

Comment: @Mitch Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. The point I was trying to make was just to advise against doing any custom formatting. If you format strings and pass those to ETW, you're adding overhead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The translation performed by the EventSource manifest generator is

```
{0} -> %1
...
{n} -> %(n+1)

&   -> &amp;
<   -> &lt;
>   -> &gt;
'   -> &apos;
"   -> &quot;
```

For reference, the conversion happens in [`string EventProviderBase.TranslateToManifestConvention(string)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/diagnostics/eventing/eventsource.cs,aa1f4bdcab84d70d).

Then you end up at the message compiler.  [Escapes are as follows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd996906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
%n[!format_specifier!]  Describes an insert. Each insert is an entry in the 
    Arguments array in the FormatMessage function. The value of n can be a number 
    between 1 and 99. The format specifier is optional. If no value is specified, 
    the default is !s!. For information about the format specifier, see wsprintf. 
    The format specifier can use * for either the precision or the width. When 
    specified, they consume inserts numbered n+1 and n+2.

%0  Terminates a message text line without a trailing newline character. This can 
    be used to build a long line or terminate a prompt message without a trailing 
    newline character.

%.  Generates a single period. This can be used to display a period at the 
    beginning of a line, which would otherwise terminate the message text.

%!  Generates a single exclamation point. This can be used to specify an 
    exclamation point immediately after an insert.

%%  Generates a single percent sign.

%n  Generates a hard line break when it occurs at the end of a line. This can be 
    used with FormatMessage to ensure that the message fits a certain width.

%b  Generates a space character. This can be used to ensure an appropriate number 
    of trailing spaces on a line.

%r  Generates a hard carriage return without a trailing newline character.
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So the format strings passed are actually being run through some kind of search/replace or regex before being fed to ETW, despite looking like string.Format() format strings. Great!

Comment: @bwerks, I ended up needing this information for a project I am currently working on, so it ended up being quite serendipitous.  I could not get newlines to work, though.  Did you ever figure that one out?

Comment: I never did, no--I can't quite remember the behavior, but it seemed as though it was actually escaping the % symbols itself on the way in, or something. We decided we could live with the weirdness and stopped investing time into it, unfortunately.

Comment: Haha, that was my determination too.  Based off of looking at the compiled resources, all of the `\r\n`'s were getting substituted with `%r%n`, but Event Viewer did not include a linebreak.

Comment: This is messed up for the web. I get `%%r%%n` when logging from web applications.

Comment: Example: `Message on first line. Note the preceding space before the backslash \nMessage on new line.` I got newlines working by including spaces before the escape characters. The behaviour is valid for both hard line breaks and hard carriage returns. The output looks the same for both.